# Error in Parse JSON step in Microsoft Flow

Tags: json, jsonschema, power-automate

Sorry for the long question, but I wanted to include all the JSON to get the best help.

we are getting an error parsing JSON from an HTTP Get request in our flow.

Here is the schema we are using in our Parse JSON step:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "d": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "results": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "__metadata": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "id": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "uri": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "type": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "Alerts": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "__deferred": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "uri": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "Groups": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "__deferred": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "uri": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "Id": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "IsHiddenInUI": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "LoginName": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Title": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "PrincipalType": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "Email": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "IsEmailAuthenticationGuestUser": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "IsShareByEmailGuestUser": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "IsSiteAdmin": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "UserId": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "__metadata": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "type": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "NameId": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "NameIdIssuer": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                            "__metadata",
                            "Alerts",
                            "Groups",
                            "Id",
                            "IsHiddenInUI",
                            "LoginName",
                            "Title",
                            "PrincipalType",
                            "Email",
                            "IsEmailAuthenticationGuestUser",
                            "IsShareByEmailGuestUser",
                            "IsSiteAdmin",
                            "UserId"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

we are only interested in the Email property that we want to use to send approvals...

here are the INPUTS results of the Parse JSON step that fails:

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "https://*********.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetUserById(1691)",
          "uri": "https://*********.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetUserById(1691)",
          "type": "SP.User"
        },
        "Alerts": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "https://*********.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetUserById(1691)/Alerts"
          }
        },
        "Groups": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "https://*********.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetUserById(1691)/Groups"
          }
        },
        "Id": 1691,
        "IsHiddenInUI": false,
        "LoginName": "i:0#.f|membership|Surnamei@Company.org.uk",
        "Title": "Firstname Surname",
        "PrincipalType": 1,
        "Email": "Surnamef@Company.org.uk",
        "Expiration": "",
        "IsEmailAuthenticationGuestUser": false,
        "IsShareByEmailGuestUser": false,
        "IsSiteAdmin": false,
        "UserId": {
          "__metadata": {
            "type": "SP.UserIdInfo"
          },
          "NameId": "10033fff9fe67a30",
          "NameIdIssuer": "urn:federation:microsoftonline"
        },
        "UserPrincipalName": "Surnamef@Company.org.uk"
      },
      }
    ]
  }
```

here is the schema from the run results of the Parse JSON that fails:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "d": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "results": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "__metadata": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "uri": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "type": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              },
              "Alerts": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "__deferred": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "uri": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "Groups": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "__deferred": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "uri": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "Id": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "IsHiddenInUI": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "LoginName": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "Title": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "PrincipalType": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "Email": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "IsEmailAuthenticationGuestUser": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "IsShareByEmailGuestUser": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "IsSiteAdmin": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "UserId": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "__metadata": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "NameId": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "NameIdIssuer": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "__metadata",
              "Alerts",
              "Groups",
              "Id",
              "IsHiddenInUI",
              "LoginName",
              "Title",
              "PrincipalType",
              "Email",
              "IsEmailAuthenticationGuestUser",
              "IsShareByEmailGuestUser",
              "IsSiteAdmin",
              "UserId"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the error in the step from the run history:

```
[
  {
    "message": "Invalid type. Expected Object but got Null.",
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "linePosition": 0,
    "path": "d.results[3].UserId",
    "schemaId": "#/properties/d/properties/results/items/properties/UserId",
    "errorType": "type",
    "childErrors": []
  }
]
```

so how can I change the schema to successfully retrieve the email

Comment: JSON Schema is for validation. The error message you are seeing is saying the data you are testing is invalid according to the schema. The value at `path` is Null and not an object. I would suggest you look at your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by *UserId* being null in several elements of the data received from the HTTP Get, while that is set as **required** in the JSON Schema...

initially we solved it by using the below in the HTTP Get:

```
_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('Legal Owners')/users?$filter=UserId+ne+null
```

Then we were given a better and more elegant solution on the [Power Platform Community](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Parse-JSON-step-failing-with-null-error/m-p/333178#M35989):

in the *Apply to each* step use:

```
body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')?['d']?['results']
```

and **within the loop** use:

```
item()?['Email']
```